# Programmatically connect to multiple chrome-casts

Tags: .net, powershell, google-chrome-extension, casting, chromecast

I need to write an application that casts different things to 7 different screens.

But to cast to 7 different screens from the same computer one has to create 7 different users on Google Chrome, they then have to obviously click the cast icon using the extension, and click on which chromecast to cast too.

So are there any resources out there that will help me out a bit? Could i use powershell?

Comment: I don't know, but you can write an external application and access it via [nativeMessaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/nativeMessaging).

Comment: The Chrome sender app API uses Javascript; why does your question have the .net tag?